# Nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance. Works in other UITableViews

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITableViewCell which I've written in a separate .xib file, for use in a couple of different UITableViews. The TableViews all inherit from a class which registers the UINib for use, with the identifier "SpecialCell".

For all but one of the TableViews, the cell gets dequeued and works fine. However, for one of them I get this error:

*** Assertion failure in -[app.MyTableView _dequeueReusableViewOfType:withIdentifier:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore/UIKit-3899.13.13/UITableView.m:8546

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'invalid nib registered for identifier (SpecialCell) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance'

I'm dequeuing the cell with the exact same code as in the other TableViews, and I cannot figure out why this issue is happening in only one of the ViewControllers.

I've seen a few answers relating to the same message, but none seem to apply here. There aren't any extraneous top level objects (and since the cell loads perfectly well in other ViewControllers then I don't think this can really be the root issue).

This is the code that I'm using (same in each ViewController) to dequeue the cell.

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SpecialCell", for: indexPath) as? SpecialCell else {
    print("can't load SpecialCell")
    return UITableViewCell()
}
return cell
```

(For what it's worth, the print statement in that else clause doesn't get run).

If anyone has any clues on what the issue might be, I'd really appreciate it!

Edit: [Picture of the SpecialCell nib as requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao13e.png)

Comment: Can you edit with an image of your `xib`.Also have you registered your `cell`?

Comment: Added a screenshot there. And yes, the cell is registered, and dequeues correctly in other tableviews.

Comment: Why do you have a ticketView? I mean there already a view. Try to delete this view.

Comment: If it works on all the other tableviews, I suspect you've setup the new tableView differently to the others. Maybe you are not using the sub class that inherits all the logic you mentioned. If thats not it, you really need to post more of your code (how the tableviews are being setup etc.) and a screenshot of the tableviewcell in interface builder

Comment: I’ve been over it with a fine tooth comb at this point and can’t find any difference in the way this particular tableview is structured. I’m inclined to just rebuild it and see if that works, to be completely sure there isn’t something funky I’m missing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to use same reuse identifier among different classes. Every time you use TableView cell inside a TableView register it with a unique identifier. This makes easier for iOS to identify your cell. Even in doc they have specified that if you reuse the same identifier the old registration will become invalid.

> If you previously registered a class or nib file with the same reuse
>   identifier, the nib you specify in the nib parameter replaces the old
>   entry. You may specify nil for nib if you want to unregister the nib
>   from the specified reuse identifier.

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614937-register)

Comment: Thanks, I’ll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a ticketView? I mean there is already a view. Try to delete this ticketView.
Also in the `viewDidLoad` register like this :
`tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "cellName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")`

Comment: TicketView is a view that’s reused elsewhere, not just in this cell, hence that structure. Using that method for registering doesn’t work either. Again, the issue doesn’t seem to be with the cell itself, it works with every other tableview in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error while mistakenly dragged a label outlet to the XIB table view cell, which contained the label, so I just missed the label and released on the canvas behind it. Removing it and dragging it to the label solved it of course.